# How to call external API from AWS Step Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda, service-worker, aws-step-functions

I want to implement a simple sequence of tasks on AWS Step Function. Something like next:
[image: Step Function Diagram]

- I can't fire and forget External API, because I need a response from it. So it is a bad idea to wrap it in a lambda function.
- I can't implement the External API task on Lambda Function, because work exceeds [lambda limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

The best way that I see is the implementation of a call to External API from the task of Step Function. If I understand correctly it is possible to do with [Activities](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-activities.html) and Worker.

I see some Ruby example, but it isn't clear for me.
Could anybody suggest me a good tutorial with clear examples of similar implementation?

PS: External API I could wrap in anything on EC2.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you **can't** call an external API from the Step Function.
You have to wrap the call in a Lambda.

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html):

> Step Functions supports the ability to call HTTP endpoints through API Gateway, but does not currently support the ability to call generic HTTP endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

AWS just released the ability to call third party API's from step function using the `Call third-pary API` actions which now enabled you to call external apis without a lambda wrapper!

Answer (score 0):

What Lambda limitation prevents you from wrapping the external API? If Lambda indeed cannot be used, depending on your usage, you may choose:

- If the traffic is not stable/continuous, take a look at the ECS task which can be called by Step Functions (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connectors-ecs.html), because it can save you the cost of paying idle.
- Otherwise, using EC2/ECS and Activity is the way to go.